# class cast exception for the same class in jboss

Tags: jboss, war, ear

I m using jboss as application server. I got the classCastException for the same class. I think there is problem with class loader. Both EAR and WAR uses different class loader for loading the same class, that's why classCastException is occurred. So, can anyone tell me how I can use the EAR class loader in WAR.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have added the same jar file in both your war and your ear, and you use it in your ear. Move it out from the war and into your ear and you'll get a better result.